# Modify variable in lambda expression

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to convert a for loop into a java-8 forEach based statement. The loop is breaking out when it encounters a '\n' character in the array and then also returns the index of that location in the array.

```
protected Integer skipLine(byte[] buf,Integer len, Integer i) {
    for(;i<len;i++) {
        if(buf[i] == '\n') {
            newLine();
            return ++i;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Java-8 equivalent:

```
protected Integer skipLine(byte[] buf,Integer len, Integer i) {
    IntStream stream = IntStream.range(i, len).map(j -> buf[j]); // this is necessary because there's no ByteStream
    stream.forEach(??);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: What’s the meaning of `i`? And why are you using `Integer` instead of `int`?

Comment: IMHO it would make more sense to incorporate streams outside this method and restructure your code if necessary. `Arrays.binarySearch` seems more appropriate for this section of code.

Comment: @Holger this is just some legacy code I'm using to practice Java 8. I agree, though, that Integer should be replaced with int.

Comment: @zeroflagL Yes, Arrays.binarySearch seems more apt. However, why would I need to incorporate streams outside this method additionally?

Comment: Not additionally, but instead. Streams are tools for functional programming and I wouldn't consider `skipLine` very functional. As a side note: I wouldn't expect a function named `skipLine` to return something. I assume the buffer is an input and you generate some output. That would be a task for a stream, but at a larger scale, not within this method. I don't know your code, so these are just assumptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method will return the result you want.

It creates an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) going from `i` to `len` exclusive (with the help of [`range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-)), then filters the element of the buffer being equal to `\n` (with the help of [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#filter-java.util.function.IntPredicate-)). When one is found, `newLine()` is called. Since we're only interested in the first one, we call [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#findFirst--). If none was found then we return `len` (with the help of [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#orElse-int-)).

```
protected Integer skipLine(byte[] buf,Integer len, Integer i) {
    return IntStream.range(i, len)
                    .filter(n -> buf[n] == '\n')
                    .peek(n -> newLine())
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(len-1) + 1;
}
```

As a side-note, you should change the input argument to `int` instead of `Integer` (and like-wise, return `int` instead of `Integer`).

Comment: I can see that this is more readable. Let's assume there was no such a thing as binary search for the moment. Is this java-8 way better in terms of performance? May be this is not a good example for asking questions about performance, but I'm still curious if this is any better than the original for loop.

Comment: I noticed that peek() here takes in only an IntConsumer. Isn't there a cleaner way of avoiding having to specify the parameter since it's anyway not being used in the body?

Comment: @user640378 Talking about performance is tricky, a benchmark would be needed but I would assume it is about the same. As for your second comment, no, we have to ignore it, there is no other way (and it kind of makes sense: why would you want to call a method that doesn't depend on what you're looping?)

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to cram too much into one stream.  Whatever you win in line count you lose in clarity.

If you had to describe your method in English, you would say "I want to find the first linefeed that's between `i` and `len` excluding `len`.  If I found it, I want to call `newLine()` and return the index right after the linefeed.  If I didn't find it, I want to just return `len`."

Consider the following implementation, which reads exactly like the English description of the method.

```
protected Integer skipLine(byte[] buf, Integer len, Integer i) {
    OptionalInt linefeed = IntStream.range(i, len)
            .filter(n -> buf[n] == '\n')
            .findFirst();

    if (linefeed.isPresent()) {
        newLine();
        return linefeed.getAsInt() + 1;
    } else {
        return len;
    }
}
```

You could make it shorter without losing too much clarity by using the stream to search for position after linefeed and then only having one return statement with `.orElse(len)`, but that's a matter of taste.

Please avoid using `peek` with `findFirst` for side effects as suggested in the other answer.  It relies on unspecified behavior and can result in surprises.  Consider the following code (with static import of `Arrays.asList`):

```
List<List<Integer>> numbers = asList(
        asList(1, 2), 
        asList(3, 4)
);

int one = numbers.stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .findFirst()
        .get();
```

What does this code output?  Since you are using `findFirst`, you might expect `peek` to only print the first element of the stream, which is 1.  But, in fact, the above code will print 1 2.  `peek` is **not** constrained to only act upon exactly as many elements as it takes to satisfy `findFirst`.

Comment: You are right about `peek` and `findFirst` when a call to `flatMap` is made before but this is not the case in my answer, and since the Stream is created in the method (so directly controlled), there is no unspecified behaviour.

Comment: @Misha can you explain how you would make it shorter without losing too much clarity? Using the stream to search for a position after linefeed requires OptionalInt arithmetic, which is not allowed.

Comment: @user640378 what do you mean by "not allowed"?  Is this homework with some specific restrictions?

Comment: @Tunaki the `flatMap` example is to illustrate the fact that `peek` is not required to only see as many elements as it takes to satisfy `findFirst`.  Although your code works correctly under the current java implementation, it does rely on unspecified behavior or `peek`.

Comment: @Misha I'm referring to your statement in the answer: "You could make it shorter without losing too much clarity by using the stream to search for position after linefeed and then only having one return statement with .orElse(len), but that's a matter of taste." 

I tried doing this, but noticed I can't add OptionalInts. `OptionalInt nextByte = IntStream.range(i, len).filter(n -> buf[n] == '\n').findFirst() + 1;`